# Law of the iterated logarithm in C([0,1])

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots $ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables
with values in the space $C([0,1])$ of real continuous functions on $[0,1$].
Assume for simplicity that the
$X_i$'s are centered, in the sense that $E( X_i(t)) = 0$ for $t \in [0,1]$).
Are there any necessary and sufficient
conditions (on the common distribution of the $X_i$'s) in order that
$$
    \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac {1}{\sqrt {2n \ln \ln (n)}} \, \| X_1 + \cdots +X_n \|_\infty < \infty
$$
almost surely (where $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ is the sup norm)? What would then be the value of the limsup?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is the so-called bounded law of the iterated logarithm (BLIL) in $C[0,1]$.

A necessary and sufficient condition for the BLIL in an arbitrary real separable Banach space $B$ was given by Ledoux and Talagrand '88 -- see e.g. Theorem A in the [subsequent paper by Einmahl '93](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176989009). This necessary and sufficient condition involves the boundedness of $(S_n/\sqrt{n\ln\ln n})_{n\ge3}$ in probability, which may be hard to verify in $C[0,1]$.

A sufficient condition (involving a certain, rather weak condition on the modulus of continuity of $X_1(\cdot)$) for the BLIL in $C[0,1]$ is implied by Theorem 2.1 in the  [earlier paper by Kuelbs '76](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00534775).